# Creating a print button based on conditional criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, button, printing, conditional-statements, worksheet

So first my disclaimer. While I have some programming background, im not proficient in VB scripting so I may need some hand holding on this but I am mighty grateful for any help you wonderful people can render.

Im creating a print button that will print a worksheet based on criteria that the user will type in. Well basically I need the script to check certain cells in a row and if there is data in those cells, move to the next line. Rinse and repeat until you get to a row with no data in those certain cells and then automatically print the correct number of pages based on the data. I hope that makes sense. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please share your work. We can suggest/help.

Comment: I have none. I have little snippets of code Ive found while researching but with no formal training in VB Scripting its like decyphering a code. Which is why Im here asking for help. Im not asking you to do it for me, im asking you to point me in the right direction. Not sure why you feel that deserves a negative on my account but whatever.

Comment: So you are looking for the first blank cell?
 MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C:C="",0),0). This will return you the row number of the first blank cell in column C.

Comment: If you are looking for the first blank cell in more than one column, then take a min, like this. =MIN(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C:C="",0),0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D:D="",0),0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried writing a piece of code to check certain columns and return the value when all of those columns are blank. Hope that helps you

```
   Sub Printing()
        Dim CheckCol1 As Integer, CheckCol2 As Integer
        Dim rowCount As Integer, rowCount1 As Integer, rowCount2 As Integer, currentRow As Integer
        Dim currentRowValue1 As String, currentRowValue2 As String
        Dim found As String
        found = "No"
        CheckCol1 = 1   'column A has a value of 1
        CheckCol2 = 2   'column B has a value of 2

        rowCount1 = Cells(Rows.Count, CheckCol1).End(xlUp).Row
        rowCount2 = Cells(Rows.Count, CheckCol2).End(xlUp).Row
        rowCount = Application.Max(rowCount1, rowCount2)

        ' find the first blank cell on both the columns
        For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
            currentRowValue1 = Cells(currentRow, CheckCol1).Value
            currentRowValue2 = Cells(currentRow, CheckCol2).Value

            If (IsEmpty(currentRowValue1) Or currentRowValue1 = "") And (IsEmpty(currentRowValue2) Or currentRowValue2 = "") Then
              MsgBox ("No data on Column A and B in row" & currentRow)
              found = "Yes"
            End If
        Next
        If found = "No" Then ' This will return rowcount+1 when the columns have values throughout the range 
           MsgBox ("No data on Column A and B in row" & rowCount + 1)
         End If

    End Sub
```

Note:- You can increase the number of columns to be checked by adding few variables. You can try Adding third column by adding Checkcol3, rowcount3, currentrowvalue3 and adding one more condition to the if clause

Comment: No this will work perfectly. I can then add the .printout based on what page it finds the first row or column that is completely empty. Thank you.